# using a LEFT OUTER JOIN on something COALESCED

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table where I only want to look at AB

```
ID     CODE       COUNT   
102    AB         9
101    AB         8
100    AC         23    //not important!!!!
99     AB         7
98     AB         6
97     AB         5
96     AB         0
```

Conversed to this

```
ID    NEWID     CODE       COUNT   
102   102       AB         9
101   101       AB         8
99    100       AB         7
98    99        AB         6
97    98        AB         5
96    97        AB         0
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT t.ID, @NEWID := COALESCE(@NEWID - 1, t.ID) AS NEWID, t.CODE, t.COUNT
FROM
(SELECT ID, CODE, COUNT FROM some_table WHERE CODE = 'AB' ORDER BY ID DESC) t,
(SELECT @NEWID := NULL) _uv;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b8b/1/0

And now I want to count the difference of each consecutive NEWID.

So

```
Step 1: 9 - 8 = 1
Step 2: 8 - 7 = 1
Step 3: 7 - 6 = 1
Step 4: 6 - 5 = 1
Step 5: 5 - 0 = 5
```

I'm used to doing this with

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table t2 ON t.ID = ( t2.ID + 1 )
```

And then taking the difference between t2.count and t.count,
but now when I'm using COALESCE, I cannot select this NEWID, so the code below does not work.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table t2 ON t.NEWID = ( t2.NEWID + 1 )
```

So how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Usually this points to a fundamental flaw in your database!

Comment: @Strawberry because sometimes the data that comes into the database (which is being sent by a gprs) is not what it should be. Sometimes the 'count' is suddenly zero while I have to keep counting(due to a reset in the gprs).. Hope this clarifies..?

Comment: @Strawberry I only want to count from a specific moment in time, and this moment can vary, and what is 'ids'?

Comment: I get that you have to keep counting, but I don't understand why you have to reset IDs. That would seem to undermine the integrity of your data. Also, I suspect that your sample dataset is inadequate to the task of properly explaining your problem.

Comment: There are multiple (but likewise)systems inserting data in the same table, and indeed, the sample dataset is only for explaining the problem and very different from the actual dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, so *that's* why you needed sequential IDs. Well, you can use user variables for this, too, and you don't even need `NEWID`! Since you're doing stuff like this, you'd do well to [read up on how user variables work](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html).

```sql
SELECT
    t.ID, t.CODE, t.COUNT,
    @PREVCOUNT - t.COUNT DIFFERENCE,
    @PREVCOUNT := t.COUNT  -- Updates for the next iteration, so it
                           -- must come last!
FROM
    (SELECT ID, CODE, COUNT FROM some_table WHERE CODE = 'AB' ORDER BY ID DESC) t,
    (SELECT @PREVCOUNT := NULL) _uv;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b8b/36/0)

Comment: Thanks alot!! This works! Only now I have a small problem more, what if @PREVCOUNT - t.COUNT < 0.. Then I dont want to add this to the user variable 'prevcount'. Any tips?

Comment: You could use a simple `CASE` expression. Something like `@PREVCOUNT := CASE WHEN DIFFERENCE < 0 THEN @PREVCOUNT ELSE t.COUNT END`. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 t1.ID as ID1, 
 t2.ID as ID2, 
 t1.CODE as CODE, 
 t1.COUNT as C1, 
 t2.COUNT as C2,
 t2.COUNT - t1.COUNT as DIFF
FROM 
  some_table t1 
  INNER JOIN some_table t2 ON t1.ID < t2.ID AND t1.CODE = t2.CODE
WHERE
  t1.CODE='AB'
  AND NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM some_table t3
    INNER JOIN some_table t4 ON t3.ID < t4.ID and t3.CODE = t4.CODE
    WHERE 
        t3.CODE='AB'
        AND t1.ID = t3.ID
        AND t4.ID < t2.ID 
      )
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

Another way will be to use LIMIT:

```
SELECT
 t.ID1 AS ID,
 t.CODE as CODE,
 t.C2-t.C1 AS DIFF
FROM
(
SELECT 
 t1.ID as ID1, 
 t1.CODE as CODE, 
 t1.COUNT as C1, 
 (SELECT t.COUNT 
  FROM some_table t
  WHERE t.ID > t1.ID AND t.CODE=t1.CODE 
  ORDER BY t.ID 
  LIMIT 1) as C2
FROM 
  some_table t1 
WHERE
  t1.CODE='AB'
ORDER BY t1.ID) t
ORDER BY t.ID1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b8b/24

Comment: Seems OK untill I use it on (much)larger tables :(. Is there not a way to tag NEWID using left outer join? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why do you need NEWID? and what is the problem on larger tables?

Comment: Mistake! There was no problem, it was my browser which caused phpmyadmin to appear to crash.. (chrome O.o) The script is fine! Though I prefer using user variables :) Still thanks alot!

Comment: I prefer this option, because it is RDBMS independent, otherwise variables are great.